# How to show multiple tooltips on a control?

Tags: c#, winforms, tooltip

I would like to show 2 different tooltips on a control, both shown a the same time. Currently, when one is shown, and I try to show the other tooltip, the previous one disappears. How can I show both of them at the same time?

PS: The two tooltip objects are different.

Comment: Why do you want to show multiple tooltips for a single control? Why not just combine the contents of the two into a single tooltip?

Comment: Because the 2 situations happen on different locations on the control. I need to point out the locations of the events as well as the contents.

Comment: sounds like you need to have two seperate controls

Comment: I think you need to ask yourself why you're trying to show 2 tooltips at once. It doesn't sound like correct behaviour to me. Assuming you have a good reason for it, you could always hack this by having a transparent/tiny control placed at the desired location of the second tooltip and manually make a call to show the tooltip on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to customize the `ToolStripDropDown` class.  I found this article in CodeProject quite helpful in customizing my own tooltips, including popping up multiple tooltips, etc.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/simplepopup.aspx